# How did Sauron remain in control of the Nazgûl?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron, tolkiens-legendarium, nazgul

The One Ring gave Sauron control of the Nine, yet when it was taken from him he still possessed the power to control them (or, at least he regained it towards the end of the third age).  Why is this?  [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rings_of_Power#The_Nine) mentions that he drew the Nine to him, but not how.

Comment: I might be wrong, but what I recall is that Sauron's soul [or something similar] is part of what forged the ring, which made them be controlled by Sauron, and the reason that makes Sauron seek the ring (to restore his power)

Comment: @Oak I think yes, he put a bit of himself IIRC into the forging process (From the books). But how can his soul poured into a ring, that he does not possess command the Nine, without the ring?

Comment: As I recall (but have no reference to back it up), the One Ring is what enabled Sauron to corrupt the Ring Bearers (well, the Nine at least); once corrupted, however, they served Sauron, not the Ring. "In the darkness bind them" means to bind them to Sauron's will.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

After the wearers of the Nine Rings had become the Ringwraiths, Sauron -- who at that time still possessed the One Ring -- took their Rings from them. In a letter, Professor Tolkien wrote,

> Sauron ... still through their nine rings **(which he held)** had
>   primary control of their wills.

from *The Letters of J. R. R. Tolkien*; emphasis mine.

Comment: Ah, now that I did not know.  Awesome.

Comment: Why would he take their rings?

Comment: @Petersaber To control them, it appears.

Comment: @Petersaber - collateral on their souls. "Witch King of Angmar! You come to me seeking power! What would you give for such power!" "Anything, Lord Sauron! Anything!!" "Even your SOUL...?????" "Even that, my lord - ANYTHING! Just...not my ring. I love my ring. My little ring...my little ring...I like to play with my little ring..." "A RING?!?!? GIVE IT TO ME!!!!" "No!" "YES!!" "NO!!!" "YESSSSS!!!!!!!!" "Oooh, I just *love* those sssssibilant esssssesssss!!!! OK, here's the ring. Give me power!!!!" "Power, shmower. I've got the ring. You do as I say, puppet-boy!" "Oh, drat..."

Comment: @BobJarvis I thought he controlled them through a connection between their Rings and One Ring, so in my mind it didn't make sense to "sever" that connection while he still had the One Ring.

Answer (score 25):

Despite no longer being in control of the One Ring, Sauron still maintained control over the Nazgûl through each of the Nine rings which he regained while still in control of the One.

Letter #246 explains that even if someone else had control over the One Ring, the Nazgûl would still ultimately obey Sauron:

> Sauron sent at once the Ringwraiths. They were naturally fully instructed, and in **no way deceived as to the real lordship of the Ring**...But the situation was now different to that under Weathertop, where Frodo acted merely in fear and wished only to use (in vain) the Ring's subsidiary power of conferring invisibility. He had grown since then. Would they have been immune from its power if he claimed it as an instrument of command and domination? Not wholly. I do not think they could have attacked him with violence, nor laid hold upon him or taken him captive; **they would have obeyed or feigned to obey any minor command of his that did not interfere with their errand - laid upon them by Sauron, who still through their nine rings (which he held) had primary control of their wills**..

[246 From a letter to Mrs Eileen Elgar (drafts) September 1963](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0618056998)

Comment: I've removed the link to pirated material and replaced it with something more appropriate.  I understand that you were very much most probably just using it to support your answer (which IMO is the correct answer), but it still shouldn't have been there.

Comment: Also, Sauron possessed the ruling ring and bossed the  Nazgûl around for over 1800 years before it got cut from his hand. They knew upon which side their bread was buttered, thin though it may be.

Comment: I actually think this is a mistake by JRRT.  If nobody can use the ring to any effect against him, then Saruman or Denethor have no reason to use the ring against Sauron to save themselves.

Comment: @Oldcat - also from Letter 246: "*It was part of the essential deceit of the Ring to fill minds with imaginations of supreme power*" - so Saruman, or Denethor, or anyone else would be *deceived* by the Ring into thinking they could use it.

Comment: Sure, but at this point they don't have the ring.  So it can't be the one filling their minds.  It would either be Sauron through the Palantir, or ring lore that both have studied.

Comment: Back in the 70s a wargame company SPI made a War of the Rings game and had an optional rule that let Saruman or Aragorn claim the ring.  The wraiths started changing sides from 9 down to 1 over the turns.

Comment: @JimmyShelter Thanks for changing the link. It slipped past me the dubious nature of the previous one.

Comment: @Oldcat - already discussed (and disagreed on) at some length here - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48180/would-the-one-ring-even-work-for-anyone-but-sauron/48186 - I'd suggest reading that (but take a deep breath cos it's a long dive in) for the arguments for and against the theory.

Answer (score 8):

From Unfinished Tales "Hunt for the Ring":

> At length Sauron resolved that no others would serve him in this case but his mightiest servants, the Ringwraiths, who had no will but his own, being each utterly subservient to the ring that had enslaved him, which Sauron held.

Comment: Great find, thanks.  My copy has different wording but the same gist: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LgVpM.jpg